# ImageView with right-aligned, cropped, unscaled content

Tags: android, imageview, crop, alignment

I've been searching, fiddling and crying for hours but can't figure out how to place an image into an ImageView and have the image presented unscaled, right-aligned and have the overflow beyond the left side of the ImageView cropped.

The ImageView is defined as such:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bleh"
></ImageView>
```

`layout_width` is set to `fill_parent` to stretch and shrink the ImageView to suit the screen.

`layout_height` is set to `wrap_content` because the ImageView will always have a fixed height, determined from the image.

I have not defined a `layout_gravity="right"` because my understanding is this relates to the positioning of the ImageView inside its parent, which in this case has no effect because the ImageView's width is set to fill_parent.

Using the above layout code, the image scales to fit the ImageView.  The only way I can prevent the scaling is by setting `android:scaleType="center"`, which prevents scaling, but unfortunately centres the image.

Ay ideas?  Otherwise, I'm currently toying with the following alternatives:

- Subclass ImageView and implement my own onDraw() method.
- Place the full-image-sized ImageView into a ScrollView and fix the scrolling to the far right (and disable any indication that it is a scroll view).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a scroll view - put the image inside of a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.  Make the layout's layout_width fill_parent and the the layout_height wrap content.  Then on the ImageView use layout gravity right and wrap_content for both the width and the height.

```
<LinerLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:layout_gravity="right"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/bleh"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Extreme big like! :D

Answer (score 2):

@harmanjd: you have done a little error, this is the correct way:
(sorry i can't comment your answer)

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="right">

    <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bleh"/>
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want TextView (for name) and Imageview (for Image) in one row and I want TextView Left algn and Imageview Right align. can you please suggest me a way?

Comment: sorry, i think it's not correct way to request a suggest...this post has another request